# Juntar várias planilhas de excel em uma só

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Olá, gente. Então, eu tenho uma pasta no meu computador onde são jogadas várias planilhas e eu preciso das planilha1.xlsm, planilha2.xlsm, planilha3.xlsm... porém elas estão juntas de outras planilhas pois essa pasta no computador é uma pasta pública. Vários arquivos são jogados lá então corre o risco de eu sem querer importar esses arquivos juntos.

A partir disso preciso juntar os dados de uma determinada aba dessas planilhas. Exemplo, tenho 3 abas em cada porém todas possuem as mesmas colunas e as mesmas abas, apenas dados diferentes.

Quando eu importar preciso jogar em uma aba só um debaixo do outro.

Outro ponto é que esses arquivos são sempre atualizados mas preciso manter os dados das tabelas antigas + o novo pondo embaixo...

Como faço para pegar esses arquivos em específico levando em consideração que essas planilhas são sempre atualizadas? Não tô sabendo começar. Achei esse código na internet, pois vou usar vba:

```
Option Explicit
 
Private Function ListaArquivos(ByVal Caminho As String) As String()
 
'Atenção: Faça referência à biblioteca Micrsoft Scripting Runtime
Dim FSO As New FileSystemObject
Dim result() As String
Dim Pasta As Folder
Dim Arquivo As File
Dim Indice As Long
 
ReDim result(0) As String
If FSO.FolderExists(Caminho) Then
    Set Pasta = FSO.GetFolder(Caminho)
 
    For Each Arquivo In Pasta.Files
      Indice = IIf(result(0) = "", 0, Indice + 1)
      ReDim Preserve result(Indice) As String
      result(Indice) = Arquivo.Name
    Next
End If
 
ListaArquivos = result
ErrHandler:
    Set FSO = Nothing
    Set Pasta = Nothing
    Set Arquivo = Nothing
End Function
 
Public Sub UnirTodos()
On Error GoTo trata_saida:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    
    Dim arquivos() As String
    Dim lCtr As Long, processados As Long
    arquivos = ListaArquivos(ThisWorkbook.Path)
    For lCtr = 0 To UBound(arquivos)
        If ValidaNomeArquivo(arquivos(lCtr)) Then
            'Debug.Print arquivos(lCtr)
            Call UnirAoArquivo(arquivos(lCtr))
            processados = processados + 1
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
    MsgBox processados &amp; " arquivos processados"
trata_saida:
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
 
Private Function ValidaNomeArquivo(ByVal nomeArquivo As String) As Boolean
    Dim result As Boolean
    result = InStr(1, nomeArquivo, ThisWorkbook.Name, vbTextCompare) = 0
    If result Then
        result = result Or Right(nomeArquivo, 4) = ".xls"
        result = result Or Right(nomeArquivo, 4) = "xlsx"
        result = result Or Right(nomeArquivo, 4) = "xlsm"
    End If
    ValidaNomeArquivo = result
End Function
 
Private Sub UnirAoArquivo(ByVal nomeArquivo As String)
On Error GoTo trata_erro_uniraoarquivo
    Dim wb As Workbook, ws As Worksheet, mySheet As Worksheet, rngCopy As Range
    Set wb = Workbooks.Open(ThisWorkbook.Path &amp; "\" &amp; nomeArquivo, ReadOnly:=True)
    Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Set mySheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    
    'seleciona a regiao com conteudo
    Set rngCopy = ws.Range(ws.Cells(2, 1), ws.Cells(ws.UsedRange.Rows.Count, ws.UsedRange.Columns.Count))
    'copia
    rngCopy.Copy
    'cola no destino
    With mySheet
        Call .Paste(.Cells(.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1, 1))
    End With
    
    wb.Close
trata_saida_uniraoarquivo:
    Set wb = Nothing
    Set ws = Nothing
    Exit Sub
trata_erro_uniraoarquivo:
    GoTo trata_saida_uniraoarquivo:
End Sub
```

Esse código não tá especificando quais arquivos pegar...
Alguém para me dar uma luz?

Comment: Pode detalhar melhor a lógica que precisa?

Answer (score -1):

Olá.

Acredito que você pode utilizar o PowerQuery para juntar esse conteúdo. Vou deixar um exemplo aqui para te ajudar a adaptar para sua necessidade.

1. Em um novo excel, vá em importar dados "Da Pasta":
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
2. Selecione o caminho da pasta, na próx. tela vá em "Combinar e Transformar":
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
3. Essa tela te dará um exemplo de leitura que o excel fez na pasta, é somente um exemplo inicial, não se preocupe se não aparecer todos os arquivos ou dados aqui. Clique na Plan1 (seu nome) e "OK".
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
4. Agora estamos em uma nova janela, que é do PowerQuery da Microsoft, pesquise mais sobre ele se desejar se aprofundar ou entender melhor o seu funcionamento. Veja que é uma janela "extra" ao excel. Aqui eu fiz um exemplo filtrando somente os arquivos "Plan01.xlsx" e "Plan02.xlsx", veja que temos o "Plan03.xlsx", mas ele será filtrado na próxima tela. No painel lateral direito, você vê os passos que o PowerQuery executou, veja que agora tem um passo de "Linhas Filtradas" (as linhas, na verdade foram arquivos, pois é uma lista de arquivos).
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
5. Após finalizar todos os filtros/ajustes que você precisa para ficar somente os arquivos que você quer consolidar, clique em "Fechar e Carregar":
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
6. Pronto, agora você tem os dados dos arquivos consolidados como uma tabela única. Qdo quiser atualizar, clique em "Atualizar".
   [image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

*Edit: Os arquivos de exemplo tem esse conteúdo cada:*
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Espero ter ajudado. Marque se a resposta te ajudou. :)

Comment: Importante notar que operação do aplicativo Excel não faz parte do [escopo do site](/help/on-topic). Somente a parte de programação está no contexto (scripts, no caso da aplicação da pergunta). A qualquer momento você pode [edit] a postagem, se quiser adequar. É uma pena, pois vejo que você se esforçou para elaborar, mas se nas próximas se ativer ao tema do site, terá um retorno melhor. Para entender melhor o site: [O que é o Stack Overflow](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7256/70) - Tem outras discussões no [meta] e na [help] que podem ajudar.

Comment: Compreendo. Nesses casos, o certo é não ajudar na pergunta?

Comment: Pode ajudar, mas como o objetivo do site é ser um repositório de conhecimento amplo sobre desenvolvimento de software, teria que ser via programação. Mas tudo isso está melhor explicado nos links passados. Se aliar o empenho que teve ao desenvolver a resposta focando mais no tema do site, provavelmente vai ter um retorno melhor nas próximas. Note ainda que as pessoas negativarem é mera classificação de conteúdo, não é como "like" ou "dislike" pessoal. Inclusive, faltou na pergunta o autor fornecer um [mcve] do problema, para entendermos em qual parte é a dificuldade.

Comment: Certo, muito obrigado.